# not displaying news descripton in news api

Tags: javascript

I want to make a news giving website and i have copied front end style from bootstrap and included my javascript. when i click on the heading of the news it is not showing the description where it should show the news in dropdown way. By default it is closed and i want to open when i click on the heading

my html code:

```
    <!doctype html> <html lang="en">
    
    <head>
        <!-- Required meta tags -->
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    
        <!-- Bootstrap CSS -->
        <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.1/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-+0n0xVW2eSR5OomGNYDnhzAbDsOXxcvSN1TPprVMTNDbiYZCxYbOOl7+AMvyTG2x" crossorigin="anonymous">
    
        <title>Fastest news:- The Times of India</title> </head>
    
    <body>
        <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-dark bg-dark">
            <div class="container-fluid">
                <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Navbar</a>
                <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-bs-toggle="collapse" data-bs-target="#navbarSupportedContent" aria-controls="navbarSupportedContent" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
                <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
              </button>
                <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarSupportedContent">
                    <ul class="navbar-nav me-auto mb-2 mb-lg-0">
                        <li class="nav-item">
                            <a class="nav-link active" aria-current="page" href="#">Home</a>
                        </li>
                        <li class="nav-item">
                            <a class="nav-link" href="#">Link</a>
                        </li>
                        <li class="nav-item dropdown">
                            <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" href="#" id="navbarDropdown" role="button" data-bs-toggle="dropdown" aria-expanded="false">
                      Dropdown
                    </a>
                            <ul class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="navbarDropdown">
                                <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Action</a></li>
                                <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Another action</a></li>
                                <li>
                                    <hr class="dropdown-divider">
                                </li>
                                <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Something else here</a></li>
                            </ul>
                        </li>
                        <li class="nav-item">
                            <a class="nav-link disabled" href="#" tabindex="-1" aria-disabled="true">Disabled</a>
                        </li>
                    </ul>
                    <form class="d-flex">
                        <input class="form-control me-2" type="search" placeholder="Search" aria-label="Search">
                        <button class="btn btn-outline-success" type="submit">Search</button>
                    </form>
                </div>
            </div>
        </nav>
        <div class="container">
            <h3>Top news :<span class="badge bg-secondary my-2">By Times of India</span></h3>
            <hr>
            <div class="accordion" id="newsAccordion">
    
            </div>
    
        </div>
        </div>
    
        <!-- Optional JavaScript; choose one of the two! -->
    
        <!-- Option 1: Bootstrap Bundle with Popper -->
        <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.1/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-gtEjrD/SeCtmISkJkNUaaKMoLD0//ElJ19smozuHV6z3Iehds+3Ulb9Bn9Plx0x4" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    
        <!-- Option 2: Separate Popper and Bootstrap JS -->
    
        <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/@popperjs/core@2.9.2/dist/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-IQsoLXl5PILFhosVNubq5LC7Qb9DXgDA9i+tQ8Zj3iwWAwPtgFTxbJ8NT4GN1R8p" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
        <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.1/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-Atwg2Pkwv9vp0ygtn1JAojH0nYbwNJLPhwyoVbhoPwBhjQPR5VtM2+xf0Uwh9KtT" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    
        <script src="index.js"></script> </body>
    
    </html>
```

my javascipt code:

```
    console.log("This is news website made using javascript");
    
    let newsAccordion = document.getElementById("newsAccordion");
    
    const xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
    
    // xhr.open('GET', "https://newsapi.org/v2/top-headlines?sources=the-times-of-india&apiKey=12f651b5941b4db4867bac2e82f64287", true);
    xhr.open('GET', "news.json", true)
    
    xhr.onload = function() {
        let json = JSON.parse(this.responseText);
        let articles = json.articles;
        let newsHtml = "";
        console.log(articles);
        articles.forEach(function(element, index) {
            let news = `<div class="card">
            <div class="card-header" id="heading${index}">
                <h2 class="mb-0">
                <button class="btn btn-link collapsed" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#collapse${index}"
                    aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="collapse${index}">
                   <b>Breaking News ${index+1}:</b> ${element["title"]}
                </button>
                </h2>
            </div>
                <div id="collapse${index}" class="collapse" aria-labelledby="heading${index}" data-parent="#newsAccordion">
                <div class="card-body">${element.description}. <a href="${element['url']}" target="_blank" >Read more here</a>  </div>
            </div>
         </div>`
            newsHtml += news;
        });
    
        newsAccordion.innerHTML = newsHtml;
    }
    
    xhr.send();
```

my json file for data:

```
    {
        "status": "ok",
        "totalResults": 7,
        "articles": [{
                "source": {
                    "id": "the-times-of-india",
                    "name": "The Times of India"
                },
                "author": "Rajat Pandit",
                "title": "Army explores procurement of 350 light tanks for mountainous terrain after border standoff with China",
                "description": "India News:  The Army is now exploring the possibility of procuring 350 light tanks, which can also be transported by air, to augment its firepower in high-altitu",
                "url": "http://timesofindia.indiatimes.com/india/army-explores-procurement-of-350-light-tanks-for-mountainous-terrain-after-border-standoff-with-china/articleshow/82217825.cms",
                "urlToImage": "https://static.toiimg.com/thumb/msid-82217908,width-1070,height-580,imgsize-264639,resizemode-75,overlay-toi_sw,pt-32,y_pad-40/photo.jpg",
                "publishedAt": "2021-04-23T08:29:00Z",
                "content": "Army explores procurement of 350 light tanks for mountainous terrain after border standoff with China\r\n<ul><li>News</li>\r\n<li>India News</li>\r\n<li>Army explores procurement of 350 light tanks for mou… [+58 chars]"
            },
            {
                "source": {
                    "id": "the-times-of-india",
                    "name": "The Times of India"
                },
                "author": "Times Of India",
                "title": "PBKS vs MI Live Score, IPL 2021: Mumbai Indians seek consistency; Punjab Kings eye return to winning ways",
                "description": "IPL Live Score: Mumbai Indians seek consistency; Punjab Kings eye return to winning ways. Stay with TOI to get IPL live score, playing 11, scorecard, highlights and ball by ball score updates of the 17th IPL match between Punjab Kings and Mumbai Indians.",
                "url": "http://timesofindia.indiatimes.com/sports/cricket/ipl/live-blog/punjab-kings-vs-mumbai-indians-pbks-vs-mi-live-score-ipl-2021-17th-match-chennai/liveblog/82214950.cms",
                "urlToImage": "https://static.toiimg.com/thumb/msid-82214950,width-1070,height-580,imgsize-157009,resizemode-75,overlay-toi_sw,pt-32,y_pad-40/photo.jpg",
                "publishedAt": "2021-04-23T05:44:49Z",
                "content": "Ravi Bishnoi return on the cards?\r\nDeepak Hooda showed what he is capable of, but greater consistency would be needed from him if the team has to prosper. They bet on Australian pace imports Jhye Ric… [+3131 chars]"
            },
            {
                "source": {
                    "id": "the-times-of-india",
                    "name": "The Times of India"
                },
                "author": "PTI",
                "title": "Zydus Cadila gets DCGI nod for hepatitis drug for Covid-19 treatment",
                "description": "India News: Drug firm Zydus Cadila on Friday said it has received restricted emergency use approval from the Indian drug regulator for the use of Pegylated Interf",
                "url": "http://timesofindia.indiatimes.com/india/zydus-cadila-gets-dcgi-nod-for-hepatitis-drug-for-covid-19-treatment/articleshow/82214909.cms",
                "urlToImage": "https://static.toiimg.com/thumb/msid-82214921,width-1070,height-580,imgsize-98052,resizemode-75,overlay-toi_sw,pt-32,y_pad-40/photo.jpg",
                "publishedAt": "2021-04-23T05:43:00Z",
                "content": null
            },
            {
                "source": {
                    "id": "the-times-of-india",
                    "name": "The Times of India"
                },
                "author": "Bloomberg",
                "title": "Even record death toll may hide extent of India’s Covid crisis",
                "description": "India News: Bodies piling up at crematoriums and burial grounds across India are sparking concerns that the death toll from a ferocious new Covid-19 wave may be m.",
                "url": "http://timesofindia.indiatimes.com/india/even-record-death-toll-may-hide-extent-of-indias-covid-crisis/articleshow/82213444.cms",
                "urlToImage": "https://static.toiimg.com/thumb/msid-82213819,width-1070,height-580,imgsize-232887,resizemode-75,overlay-toi_sw,pt-32,y_pad-40/photo.jpg",
                "publishedAt": "2021-04-23T04:41:00Z",
                "content": null
            },
            {
                "source": {
                    "id": "the-times-of-india",
                    "name": "The Times of India"
                },
                "author": "Dipak K Dash",
                "title": "Government to provide 5 kg free food grains to poor for May & June",
                "description": "India News: The government on Friday announced to provide 5 kg free food grains to the poor for May and June 2021. This will cover nearly 80 crore beneficiaries u",
                "url": "http://timesofindia.indiatimes.com/india/government-to-provide-5-kg-free-food-grains-to-poor-for-may-june/articleshow/82213582.cms",
                "urlToImage": "https://static.toiimg.com/thumb/msid-82213583,width-1070,height-580,imgsize-1921513,resizemode-75,overlay-toi_sw,pt-32,y_pad-40/photo.jpg",
                "publishedAt": "2021-04-23T04:23:00Z",
                "content": null
            },
            {
                "source": {
                    "id": "the-times-of-india",
                    "name": "The Times of India"
                },
                "author": "TIMESOFINDIA.COM",
                "title": "'Inappropriate': PM Modi objects to 'protocol break' during meeting; Delhi CM expresses regret",
                "description": "India News: Delhi chief minister Arvind Kejriwal on Friday faced flak for sharing a live telecast of an \"in-house\" meeting with Prime Minister Narendra Modi where",
                "url": "http://timesofindia.indiatimes.com/india/delhi-cmo-expresses-regret-over-televised-address-during-meeting-with-pm-modi/articleshow/82213159.cms",
                "urlToImage": "https://static.toiimg.com/thumb/msid-82213159,width-1070,height-580,imgsize-134672,resizemode-75,overlay-toi_sw,pt-32,y_pad-40/photo.jpg",
                "publishedAt": "2021-04-23T03:54:00Z",
                "content": null
            },
            {
                "source": {
                    "id": "the-times-of-india",
                    "name": "The Times of India"
                },
                "author": "Times Of India",
                "title": "Coronavirus in India live updates: Zydus' Virafin gets DCGI nod for Covid treatment",
                "description": "In yet another grim milestone, India recorded 3.3 lakh new Covid-19 cases, and 2,263 deaths in a day. Meanwhile, active cases crossed the 24-lakh mar",
                "url": "http://timesofindia.indiatimes.com/india/coronavirus-in-india-covid-19-vaccine-cases-lockdown-live-updates-23-april-2021/liveblog/82205841.cms",
                "urlToImage": "https://static.toiimg.com/thumb/msid-82205841,width-1070,height-580,imgsize-148788,resizemode-75,overlay-toi_sw,pt-32,y_pad-40/photo.jpg",
                "publishedAt": "2021-04-22T16:20:06Z",
                "content": "Zydus Cadila gets DCGI nod for hepatitis drug for Covid-19 treatment\r\nMake Covid-19 vaccination affordable, accessible through Jan Aushadi scheme: IMA\r\nThe IMA has demanded that the Covid-19 vaccine … [+4487 chars]"
            }
        ]
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Bootstrap 5 has some different classnames and datasets to use than it's predecessors.  Also, you were including the bootstrap.js twice on the page.

I removed the extra .js, added some accordian classes, and changed these 2 datasets: `data-bs-toggle="collapse" data-bs-target="#collapse${index}"`

https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.0/components/accordion/

```js
console.log("This is news website made using javascript");

let newsAccordion = document.getElementById("newsAccordion");

//const xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();

let json = getJson();
let articles = json.articles;
let newsHtml = "";
console.log(articles);
articles.forEach(function(element, index) {
  let news = `<div class="card">
            <div class="card-header" id="heading${index}">
                <h2 class="mb-0">
                <button class="btn btn-link accordion-button collapsed" type="button" data-bs-toggle="collapse" data-bs-target="#collapse${index}" 
                    aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="collapse${index}">
                   <b>Breaking News ${index+1}:</b> ${element["title"]}
                </button>
                </h2>
            </div>
                <div id="collapse${index}" class="accordion-collapse collapse" aria-labelledby="heading${index}" data-parent="#newsAccordion">
                <div class="card-body">${element.description}. <a href="${element['url']}" target="_blank" >Read more here</a>  </div>
            </div>
         </div>`
  newsHtml += news;
});

newsAccordion.innerHTML = newsHtml;


//xhr.send();


function getJson() {
  let theJson = {
    "status": "ok",
    "totalResults": 7,
    "articles": [{
        "source": {
          "id": "the-times-of-india",
          "name": "The Times of India"
        },
        "author": "Rajat Pandit",
        "title": "Army explores procurement of 350 light tanks for mountainous terrain after border standoff with China",
        "description": "India News:  The Army is now exploring the possibility of procuring 350 light tanks, which can also be transported by air, to augment its firepower in high-altitu",
        "url": "http://timesofindia.indiatimes.com/india/army-explores-procurement-of-350-light-tanks-for-mountainous-terrain-after-border-standoff-with-china/articleshow/82217825.cms",
        "urlToImage": "https://static.toiimg.com/thumb/msid-82217908,width-1070,height-580,imgsize-264639,resizemode-75,overlay-toi_sw,pt-32,y_pad-40/photo.jpg",
        "publishedAt": "2021-04-23T08:29:00Z",
        "content": "Army explores procurement of 350 light tanks for mountainous terrain after border standoff with China\r\n<ul><li>News</li>\r\n<li>India News</li>\r\n<li>Army explores procurement of 350 light tanks for mou… [+58 chars]"
      },
      {
        "source": {
          "id": "the-times-of-india",
          "name": "The Times of India"
        },
        "author": "Times Of India",
        "title": "PBKS vs MI Live Score, IPL 2021: Mumbai Indians seek consistency; Punjab Kings eye return to winning ways",
        "description": "IPL Live Score: Mumbai Indians seek consistency; Punjab Kings eye return to winning ways. Stay with TOI to get IPL live score, playing 11, scorecard, highlights and ball by ball score updates of the 17th IPL match between Punjab Kings and Mumbai Indians.",
        "url": "http://timesofindia.indiatimes.com/sports/cricket/ipl/live-blog/punjab-kings-vs-mumbai-indians-pbks-vs-mi-live-score-ipl-2021-17th-match-chennai/liveblog/82214950.cms",
        "urlToImage": "https://static.toiimg.com/thumb/msid-82214950,width-1070,height-580,imgsize-157009,resizemode-75,overlay-toi_sw,pt-32,y_pad-40/photo.jpg",
        "publishedAt": "2021-04-23T05:44:49Z",
        "content": "Ravi Bishnoi return on the cards?\r\nDeepak Hooda showed what he is capable of, but greater consistency would be needed from him if the team has to prosper. They bet on Australian pace imports Jhye Ric… [+3131 chars]"
      },
      {
        "source": {
          "id": "the-times-of-india",
          "name": "The Times of India"
        },
        "author": "PTI",
        "title": "Zydus Cadila gets DCGI nod for hepatitis drug for Covid-19 treatment",
        "description": "India News: Drug firm Zydus Cadila on Friday said it has received restricted emergency use approval from the Indian drug regulator for the use of Pegylated Interf",
        "url": "http://timesofindia.indiatimes.com/india/zydus-cadila-gets-dcgi-nod-for-hepatitis-drug-for-covid-19-treatment/articleshow/82214909.cms",
        "urlToImage": "https://static.toiimg.com/thumb/msid-82214921,width-1070,height-580,imgsize-98052,resizemode-75,overlay-toi_sw,pt-32,y_pad-40/photo.jpg",
        "publishedAt": "2021-04-23T05:43:00Z",
        "content": null
      },
      {
        "source": {
          "id": "the-times-of-india",
          "name": "The Times of India"
        },
        "author": "Bloomberg",
        "title": "Even record death toll may hide extent of India’s Covid crisis",
        "description": "India News: Bodies piling up at crematoriums and burial grounds across India are sparking concerns that the death toll from a ferocious new Covid-19 wave may be m.",
        "url": "http://timesofindia.indiatimes.com/india/even-record-death-toll-may-hide-extent-of-indias-covid-crisis/articleshow/82213444.cms",
        "urlToImage": "https://static.toiimg.com/thumb/msid-82213819,width-1070,height-580,imgsize-232887,resizemode-75,overlay-toi_sw,pt-32,y_pad-40/photo.jpg",
        "publishedAt": "2021-04-23T04:41:00Z",
        "content": null
      },
      {
        "source": {
          "id": "the-times-of-india",
          "name": "The Times of India"
        },
        "author": "Dipak K Dash",
        "title": "Government to provide 5 kg free food grains to poor for May & June",
        "description": "India News: The government on Friday announced to provide 5 kg free food grains to the poor for May and June 2021. This will cover nearly 80 crore beneficiaries u",
        "url": "http://timesofindia.indiatimes.com/india/government-to-provide-5-kg-free-food-grains-to-poor-for-may-june/articleshow/82213582.cms",
        "urlToImage": "https://static.toiimg.com/thumb/msid-82213583,width-1070,height-580,imgsize-1921513,resizemode-75,overlay-toi_sw,pt-32,y_pad-40/photo.jpg",
        "publishedAt": "2021-04-23T04:23:00Z",
        "content": null
      },
      {
        "source": {
          "id": "the-times-of-india",
          "name": "The Times of India"
        },
        "author": "TIMESOFINDIA.COM",
        "title": "'Inappropriate': PM Modi objects to 'protocol break' during meeting; Delhi CM expresses regret",
        "description": "India News: Delhi chief minister Arvind Kejriwal on Friday faced flak for sharing a live telecast of an \"in-house\" meeting with Prime Minister Narendra Modi where",
        "url": "http://timesofindia.indiatimes.com/india/delhi-cmo-expresses-regret-over-televised-address-during-meeting-with-pm-modi/articleshow/82213159.cms",
        "urlToImage": "https://static.toiimg.com/thumb/msid-82213159,width-1070,height-580,imgsize-134672,resizemode-75,overlay-toi_sw,pt-32,y_pad-40/photo.jpg",
        "publishedAt": "2021-04-23T03:54:00Z",
        "content": null
      },
      {
        "source": {
          "id": "the-times-of-india",
          "name": "The Times of India"
        },
        "author": "Times Of India",
        "title": "Coronavirus in India live updates: Zydus' Virafin gets DCGI nod for Covid treatment",
        "description": "In yet another grim milestone, India recorded 3.3 lakh new Covid-19 cases, and 2,263 deaths in a day. Meanwhile, active cases crossed the 24-lakh mar",
        "url": "http://timesofindia.indiatimes.com/india/coronavirus-in-india-covid-19-vaccine-cases-lockdown-live-updates-23-april-2021/liveblog/82205841.cms",
        "urlToImage": "https://static.toiimg.com/thumb/msid-82205841,width-1070,height-580,imgsize-148788,resizemode-75,overlay-toi_sw,pt-32,y_pad-40/photo.jpg",
        "publishedAt": "2021-04-22T16:20:06Z",
        "content": "Zydus Cadila gets DCGI nod for hepatitis drug for Covid-19 treatment\r\nMake Covid-19 vaccination affordable, accessible through Jan Aushadi scheme: IMA\r\nThe IMA has demanded that the Covid-19 vaccine … [+4487 chars]"
      }
    ]
  }

  return theJson;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.1/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-+0n0xVW2eSR5OomGNYDnhzAbDsOXxcvSN1TPprVMTNDbiYZCxYbOOl7+AMvyTG2x" crossorigin="anonymous">

<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-dark bg-dark">
  <div class="container-fluid">
    <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Navbar</a>
    <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-bs-toggle="collapse" data-bs-target="#navbarSupportedContent" aria-controls="navbarSupportedContent" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
                <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
              </button>
    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarSupportedContent">
      <ul class="navbar-nav me-auto mb-2 mb-lg-0">
        <li class="nav-item">
          <a class="nav-link active" aria-current="page" href="#">Home</a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item">
          <a class="nav-link" href="#">Link</a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item dropdown">
          <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" href="#" id="navbarDropdown" role="button" data-bs-toggle="dropdown" aria-expanded="false">
                      Dropdown
                    </a>
          <ul class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="navbarDropdown">
            <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Action</a></li>
            <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Another action</a></li>
            <li>
              <hr class="dropdown-divider">
            </li>
            <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Something else here</a></li>
          </ul>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item">
          <a class="nav-link disabled" href="#" tabindex="-1" aria-disabled="true">Disabled</a>
        </li>
      </ul>
      <form class="d-flex">
        <input class="form-control me-2" type="search" placeholder="Search" aria-label="Search">
        <button class="btn btn-outline-success" type="submit">Search</button>
      </form>
    </div>
  </div>
</nav>
<div class="container">
  <h3>Top news :<span class="badge bg-secondary my-2">By Times of India</span></h3>
  <hr>
  <div class="accordion" id="newsAccordion">

  </div>

</div>
</div>

<!-- Optional JavaScript; choose one of the two! -->


<!-- Option 2: Separate Popper and Bootstrap JS -->

<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/@popperjs/core@2.9.2/dist/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-IQsoLXl5PILFhosVNubq5LC7Qb9DXgDA9i+tQ8Zj3iwWAwPtgFTxbJ8NT4GN1R8p" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.1/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-Atwg2Pkwv9vp0ygtn1JAojH0nYbwNJLPhwyoVbhoPwBhjQPR5VtM2+xf0Uwh9KtT" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```